# List<> inside a Hashtag

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando acceder al valor de un campo de un list que a su vez está dentro de un hashtag. No tengo ni idea como se hace.
Os pongo todo el código que pueda.

```
List<obj> l = new List<objt>();
Hashtag h = new Hashtag();
int cont=0;
foreach(local loc in l)
{
    cont++
    h.add(cont,loc);
}
```

local tiene tres campos string, puebloId, name y  provId.

Yo quiero meter en un comboBox todos los name que tengan el provID=46.

Ahora tengo un Hashtag(int, local) con todas las localidades (unas 8000)

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar Hashtag puedes usar un diccionario, con ello podrías usar Linq para hacer la búsqueda que necesites, por ejemplo:

```
List<objt> l = new List<objt>();   //Siendo objt tu objeto POCO
var h = new Dictionary<int, objt>();
int cont=0;
foreach(local loc in l)
{
    cont++
    h.add(cont,loc);
}
```

Y podrías hacer búsquedas así:

```
var posi = (from d in h
            where d.provID=46
            select d.Name).ToList();
```

Y ya puedes trabajar con la lista de nombres

Comment: Vale, ya lo conseguí con esta línea:            var lista = (from d in localidades
                         where d.ProvinciaID == "46" select d.Nombre).ToList();                                Pero no me encuentra el 46 aunque sé seguro, que está porque lo veo en MySql y tampoco encuentra algunos números buscando en la list<> directamente. esto es raro :(   Gracias por tu ayuda, por cierto

Comment: Y estoy probando con otro provinciaID = "20" , que según MySql son 88 registros, pero desde el código, haciendo una lista, me salen solo dos registros...no entiendo por qué pasa esto...